# How to replace '\"' with '\\"' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, jsonparser

I have a variable `str`

```
let str = '{"id": "option2", "text": "\"hello world\""}';
```

when i try to convert to json using  `JSON.parse(str);`, it throws an error `SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 28`. I'm aware that the javascript engine reads the `str` as

`{"id": "option2", "text": ""hello world""}`, so it's expecting a `,` or a `}` after the first set of double quotes (`""`) that appear before `hello world`.

Putting an extra backslash allows `JSON.parse(str);` to run.

```
let str = '{"id": "option2", "text": "\\"hello world\\""}';
```

However, I'd like to put the extra backslash programatically. I've tried using the `replace` method. It doesn't seem to have any effect

```
let str = '{"id": "option2", "text": "\"hello world\""}'.replace(/\\\"/g, '\\\\\"');
```

`JSON.parse(str)` still throws the same error.

The result i'm looking for is such that when `str.text` is printed on the console, it's value should be `"hello world"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&quot;` if you want to KEEP the quotes

```js
let str = `{"id": "option2", "text": "&quot;hello world&quot;"}`;
let obj = JSON.parse(str);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = obj.text
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: @mrplungian No, this doesn't solve the problem. When the value for `text` is printed on the console I want it to be in quotes  i.e `"hello world"` not `hello world`. Manually typing `\"` solves that but I'm asking how to do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

the chalenge is that the beginning quoted words are differ from the end. And it seems like javascript has some bugs and doesn't allow to replace "/" using replace function. So only this code works for me

```
let sourceStr = '{"id": "option2", "text": ""hello world""}';
const searchStr = '""';

const indexes = [...sourceStr.matchAll(new RegExp(searchStr, "gi"))].map(
  (a) => a.index
);
console.log(indexes); // [26,39]

var sourceStrFixed = "";
var index;
for (index = 0; index < indexes.length; index += 2) {
  sourceStrFixed +=
    sourceStr.substring(0, indexes[index]) + '"\\"'
    + sourceStr.substring(indexes[index] + 2, indexes[index + 1]) + '\\""';
}
sourceStrFixed += sourceStr.substring(indexes[index - 1] + 2);
console.log(sourceStrFixed);
```